# Java Stream API collect method

Tags: java, java-stream

There is class Person:

```
class Person {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int amount;
}
```

and I have created `HashMap` of `Person` using external file contains lines:

```
001,aaa,23,1200
002,bbb,24,1300
003,ccc,25,1400
004,ddd,26,1500
```

***Mainclass.java***

```
public class Mainclass {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Person> al = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String,Person> hm = new HashMap<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./person.txt"))) {
        hm = br.lines().map(s -> s.split(","))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a-> new Person(a[0],a[1],Integer.valueOf(a[2]),Integer.valueOf(a[3]))));
    }
}
```

}

It works fine for `HashMap`.

How to do the same for `ArrayList`?

I tried:

```
    al = br.lines().map(s -> s.split(","))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList(a -> new Person(a[0],a[1],Integer.valueOf(a[2]),Integer.valueOf(a[3]))));
```

(IntelijIdea is underlined in red "a[0]" and says "Array type expected,found : lambda parameter")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `map` in order to map each array to a corresponding `Person` instance:

```
al = br.lines().map(s -> s.split(","))
               .map (a -> new Person(a[0],a[1],Integer.valueOf(a[2]),Integer.valueOf(a[3])))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

BTW, `Collectors.toList()` returns a `List`, not an `ArrayList` (even if the default implementation does return `ArrayList`, you can't count on that).

Comment: When the properties have `int` values as indicated in the question, using `Integer.parseInt` is preferable to `Integer.valueOf`, to avoid unnecessary boxing into `Integer` objects, just to unbox them. Besides that, I’d add a `static` factory method to the `Person` class like `Person.parse(String)` doing the conversions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `map` it to the `Person` object before trying to `collect` it:

```
.map(s -> s.split(","))
.map(a -> new Person(a[0],a[1],Integer.valueOf(a[2]),Integer.valueOf(a[3])) //here
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 1):

Why to map twice? You can directly do this,

```
.map(s -> {
            String[] parts = s.split(",");
            return new Person(parts[0],parts[1],Integer.valueOf(parts[2]),Integer.valueOf(parts[3]));
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding a `static method (or according constructor) to your person class which parses the CSV string:

```
public static Person fromCSV(String csv) {
    String[] parts = csv.split(",");
    if (parts.length != 4) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("csv has not 4 parts");
    }
    return new Person(parts[0], parts[1], Integer.parseInt(parts[2]), Integer.parseInt(parts[3]));
}
```

To read the lines you can alternatively use [`Files.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-). Using all that you can use this to create you `List<Person>`:

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("./person.txt"))) {
    List<Person> persons = lines
            .map(Person::fromCSV)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did is on correct lines, only thing missing is that you create the Person object in collect, instead you could create it inside the map method itself and return that and use the collect method with Collectors.toList() method. Below code snippet will give a good idea of what I am trying to convey:

```
al= br.lines()
      .map(s -> {
                    String[] subStrings = s.split(",");
                    return new Person(subStrings[0], subStrings[1], Integer.valueOf(subStrings[2]), Integer.valueOf(subStrings[3]));
                })
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This way you use the map method only once, and return the object that is needed which the collect method consolidates into a List. If you want it to be an ArrayList you can use Collections framework to cast List to ArrayList, but I think List should be fine for your operations.